# Trying to understand this algorithm for finding Kth min from two sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o, divide-and-conquer

> **Description:**
>  Given two sorted arrays (none-descending), find the Kth min element in T = O(lg(m + n)), m and n are length of two
>   arrays, respectively.

**Question:**
Do not understand the algorithm below about three points:

- Why we can drop the left part of A directly, when A[aPartitionIndex] < B[bPartitionIndex]?
- Why can not drop the left part of A, and the right part of B at the
  same time?
- Some "resource" said this algorithm can be applied on finding Kth min
  in N sorted arrays, how? split k into N parts?

**Code:** Java. **Solution:** Binary Search.

```
    // k is based on 1, not 0.
    public int findKthMin(int[] A, int as, int ae, 
                           int[] B, int bs, int be, int k) {

        int aLen = ae - as + 1;
        int bLen = be - bs + 1;

        // Guarantee the first array's size is smaller than the second one,
        // which is convenient to remaining part calculation.
        if (aLen > bLen) return findKthMin(B, bs, be, 
                                           A, as, ae, k);

        // Base case.
        if (aLen == 0) return B[bs + k - 1];
        if (k == 1) return Math.min(A[as], B[bs]); // k based on 1, not 0.

        // Split k, 
        // one part is distributed to A,
        // the other part is distributed to B.
        int ak = aLen < (k/2)? aLen: k/2;
        int bk = k - ak;

        // *k is based on 1, not 0.
        int aPartitionIndex = as + (ak - 1);
        int bPartitionIndex = bs + (bk - 1);

        if (A[aPartitionIndex] == B[bPartitionIndex]) {
            return A[aPartitionIndex];

        } else if (A[aPartitionIndex] < B[bPartitionIndex]) {
            // Drop the left part of A, and
            // do recursion on the right part of A, and
            // the entire current part of B.
            k = k - ak;
            return findKthMin(A, aPartitionIndex + 1, ae, 
                              B, bs, be, k);

        } else {
            // Drop the left part of B, and
            // do recursion on the entire current part of A, and
            // the right part of B.
            k = k - bk;
            return findKthMin(A, as, ae, 
                              B, bPartitionIndex + 1, be, k);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Assuming that `A` and `B` are sorted in ascending order, `A[aPartitionIndex] < B[bPartitionIndex]` implies that `A[i] < B[bPartitionIndex]` for all `i < aPartitionIndex`.

2) You can never drop the right part of an array because you don't know where they fit in the ordering.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, [1] you emphasized "ascending order", is there any problem of this Algorithm if we apply it for the arrays which contain duplicates? [2] I still cannot understand this point that "why we can drop the left part of A directly", why we can be sure our Kth min not at that part, could you give out some counter-example? I try to find the counter-example, but can not find one. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zhaonan What do duplicates have to do with sorting in ascending order? (Perhaps "non-descending" is techically more accurate.)

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, thank you for your help! But the serious problem is still that I can not prove why we can drop the left part of A directly, it seems dropping A's left part is very correct, but I just can not find why? Is there some counter-example?

Comment: @Zhaonan If doing this is correct, then there cannot be a **counter** example. On the other hand, working through an **example** and stepping through the algo with a debugger will certainly shed light on how it works.

Comment: you are right,"if doing this is correct, then there cannot be an counter example". But I think there should be some counter example for "drop the left part of A, and right part of B at the same time", but I can not find out.

Comment: @Zhaonan OIC...yes, you should be able to find a counter example to show that "drop the left part of A, and right part of B at the same time" is incorrect. I suggest first stepping through the algorithm with a debugger to get a deeper understanding of how it works. This might help you come up with the counter example you are looking for.